# RAPT - android module's check_pause, accelerometer, etc. does not work

Tags: android, python, pygame

I know people have asked questions along these lines here, but I haven't found an answer that helps me.

I've made a simple game in pygame, I'm using RAPT to port it to android. I've gotten the game to compile and run successfully on my tablet. Great.

It goes something like this:

```
import android
android.init()
import pygame
pygame.init()
def main():
     #does stuff for the game
```

The standard stuff.

But as soon as I add these lines below the import android:

```
 enable = True
 android.accelerometer_enable(enable)
```

or

```
android.check_pause()
```

or anything in the android module other than init(), the game refuses to run. ADB logcat shows that the code throws an AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute of (whatever function I tried)

I've even tried copy-pasting code from https://github.com/codetricity/accel/blob/master/main.py
and trying to compile the example code given from the RAPT download page...
https://github.com/renpytom/rapt-pygame-example/blob/master/main.py
and it returns the same kind of errors once compiled.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

In RAPT, accelerometer is seen as a 3-axis joystick. So you can use the pygame joystick module.

```
pygame.joystick.init()
num_joy_presenti = pygame.joystick.get_count()
accel = None
for i in range(num_joy_presenti):
    generico_joy = pygame.joystick.Joystick(i)
    generico_joy.init()
    if generico_joy.get_name() == "Android Accelerometer":
        accel = pygame.joystick.Joystick(i)
accel.init()
```

Then, "accel" will be your accelerometer and you can use the joystick module to get its values. Documentation here http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html#pygame.joystick.Joystick
Instead of android.check_pause you can detect pygame.APP_WILLENTERBACKGROUND and pygame.APP_WILLENTERFOREGROUND events as in the example at https://github.com/renpytom/rapt-pygame-example/blob/master/main.py